# Why are raw data analyzed rather than the probability distribution the data are sampled from?

Tags: probability, distributions, qq-plot

**QQ plots and other methods to analyze probability distributions seem to require input of the raw data itself rather than the probability distribution that the data sample. Why is that the case, even if an empirical distribution can be generated?** (I am not a mathematician, so I might be wording or thinking about that a little strangely.)

I also would like to know how I can get around this particular issue for my particular problem. I posted this yesterday, but I'm amending this today to hopefully be clearer:

**EDIT:**

A colleague calculated the number of aggregates of particles, averaged over time. These aggregates have a particular size. My understanding is that this amounts essentially to many time series -- one for each size of aggregate. Then, my colleague calculated the histogram of counts vs. size of aggregate. All I have is the histogram, but following this post, and my reading, I think I should actually be using the time series data in verifying the distribution, and so on. However, it seems that typically one time series is analyzed to get a distribution, but that is not the case here. I don't know how to analyze all of these many time series in the manner described by some of the responses, to do things like maximum likelihood estimation, and so on. Can somebody help clear up my thinking on this?

Comment: The only way to get an idea what may be true about a population is to take a sample from the distribution itself.
One way to visualize data is to look at _estimates_ such as your "number of aggregates of a particular size, divided by the total number of particles", or histograms based on the data. When you "generate" a histogram based on data, Thes procedures can provide no 'new' information about the population. Even "re-sampling" for permutation tests and bootstrap CIs depends on data at hand. These are methods of analyzing data, not methods of obtaining new information.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please elaborate about how the method I described doesn't obtain new information? This makes sense, but it also seems a bit philosophical to me. It would be great if you could clear that up.

Comment: Assuming that a coin is fair and tosses independent, I can **simulate** how many heads I might get in 100 tosses: Ten results sampled in R are  51, 47, 44, 59, 54, 64, 43, 53, 51, 55, That is a nice simulation experiment. But it tells absolutely nothing about the fairness of the quarter I have in my pocket. I have to toss the coin in my pocked lots of times to get an idea whether it is fair.

Comment: But if you analyze the probability distribution obtained from a histogram of the data (my case) or the raw data before you make a histogram (what I'd like to do and what it seems MATLAB, etc. toolboxes do) shouldn't matter, right? In both cases, you're working with a sample and not the "population," if that's the right use of the word. Perhaps I'm still being unclear, sorry.

Comment: A histogram of your **actual data** data would be helpful. But if your observations are normally distributed, then all the information you need is the number $n$ of observations, their sample mean $\bar X,$ and their sample standard deviation $S.$ That's enough info to do t test to see if the population mean is $\mu=48$ or to make a 95% CI of the parameter $\mu.$

Comment: +1 Thank you. My data are not normally distributed, and I'd like to figure out their distribution. I didn't calculate the probabilities (somebody else did) and I think working with the probabilities makes the analysis tougher than it need be. I think what I want is the time-averaged size of the aggregate formed by each particle vs. identity of each particle. But I think I would then be counting the size of the aggregates in some cases more than once because an aggregate consists of more than one particle, and the particles comprising the aggregate change over time. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Confess I have no idea what you mean by "time-averaged size of the aggregate formed by each particle vs. identity of each particle." And without access to the histogram or a more complete explanation of what you're doing, I'm unlikely to guess correctly. // You may never know the exact probability distribution involved. // Please edit you question with more context.  // I have speculated to give an Answer below that may or may not be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is what it means to do *inference*. We use what we know (data) to *infer* something about what we do not know (distribution from which the data come) that nonetheless interests us.

The empirical distribution is equivalent to the data, so analyzing one is the same as analyzing the other.

Comment: "The empirical distribution is equivalent to the data, so analyzing one is the same as analyzing the other." Is there a reason, then, that MATLAB packages (for instance) need as input the data rather than the probability distribution derived from the data? See also the above comment to my post.

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear on what you mean by an "empirical distribution". What do you mean? What are you inputting into the function? The variables could have different software structures, even if they have the same meaning, mathematically. I recently learned the 3D tensors in `R`-based `TensorFlow` do not play nice with the usual `array` operations, despite my tensor being an `array`.

Comment: I am analyzing a histogram that, from what I understand, represents the probability density function for my data. But it is "empirical" in the sense that it is just what is calculated from the data, not from an underlying equation. See paragraph 2 in my post.

Comment: I would like to figure out what should be the "raw data" (as I refer to it in my above post) but it isn't really clear to me. See the last paragraph in my post.

Comment: The histogram is a way of visualizing data, but it is not the same as the data, neither in software nor mathematically. I do not know MATLAB, but I would imagine that your histogram is, as a software object, a collection of line segments and colors, not the individual points that are used to make the histogram. // What do you use to create the histogram?

Comment: Right, but I am uncertain about what the data-to-analyze should be in my case: as I mention above, I think it should be something like the time-averaged size of the aggregate formed by each particle vs. the identity of each particle. But I think I would then be counting the size of the aggregates in some cases more than once because an aggregate consists of more than one particle, and the particles comprising the aggregate change over time. That's where I'm really stuck.

Comment: It sounds like you need to clarify the [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) of what’s going on and what should interest you before you get to the statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data for 'size' makes a histogram something like
the one below. The area of each bar represents the proportion
of the sample in the corresponding interval. The total of all
the areas is $1.$

[image]

In R, a non-plotted histogram gives information used
in plotting. [Partial printout.]

```
hist(size, plot=F)
$breaks
 [1]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120

$counts
 [1]  3 10 14 22 21 16  5  4  3  1  0  1

$density
  [1] 0.003 0.010 0.014 0.022 0.021 0.016 0.005 0.004 0.003 0.001 0.000 0.001
```

There is a summary of my 100 observations:

```
 summary(size)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  7.646  29.602  40.187  42.114  53.487 112.994 
 length(size);  sd(size)
 [1] 100        # nr of obs
 [1] 20.14539   # sample SD
```

An empirical CDF (ECDF) plot imitates the CDF of the population
from which the 100 observations were sampled.

From the shape of the histogram,
you might guess the population distribution is from the gamma
family. From that you might use the sample mean and SD to
estimate the shape parameter as about $4$ and the rate
parameter around $1/10.$ The CDF of that gamma distribution
is shown as a red curve on the ECDF plot.
That distribution has $\mu = 40, \sigma^2 = 400, \sigma=20.$
If you know about 'method-of-moments' estimation, this would
be an opportunity to use it.
[In practice, more than 100
observations would give a better chance of useful results.]

```
plot(ecdf(size))
 curve(pgamma(x, 4, .1), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

If you were able to get this far, you might use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test to see how well the ECDF matches
the possible population CDF. The test statistic $D$ of the K-S test is the maximum vertical distance between the ECDF and the CDF.

```
ks.test(size, pgamma, 4, .1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  size
D = 0.099785, p-value = 0.2723
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The test does not reject $\mathsf{Gamma}(4, .1)$ as a
possible population distribution. The difficulty is
that there are many distribution families that might
come to mind from looking at the histogram. Some
statistical computer programs have 'distribution identification' procedures that propose possibilities.
But not every distribution occurring in nature has
a 'named' distribution to go with it.

Even if you can't identify the exact distribution
of the population, you might be able to get some
information from the sample. For example, the
proportion of sizes below $35$ is about $0.4,$
from counting data points or looking at the ECDF.

```
mean(size < 35)
[1] 0.4
```

If $\mathsf{Gamma}(4,\, .1)$ happens to be the exact population distribution, then the probability that size is below $35$ is $0.4634.$

```
pgamma(35, 4, .1)
[1] 0.4633673
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear because statistics is a vast field and you are referencing some commonly used tools that may or may not be appropriate for the problem.  I will try and answer it, nonetheless.

The first question seems to be about using probability distributions.  It is important to remember that they are theoretical models of the world created by the physics of the situation.  If you change the specifics of the problem to the point that you change the physics, then you may change the probability distribution.

A probability distribution is the solution to a problem.  There are many standard named solutions because there are many types of problems that people have already tried to solve.  The empirical distribution using the histogram or other graphical methods such as kernel densities may not be representative of the population's density.  If you had a much larger sample, the shape may change.  The population density will not change, ceteris paribus.

One specific issue, though, you keep mentioning averages.  The properties of averages may not be the properties of the sample.  Anytime you aggregate information you are engaging in a mathematical transformation that will often change the rules of math regarding probability distributions.

There may already be a proposed probability distribution in the literature.  It may even have a rigorous proof around it.

The second question is implicit but missing.  The wording of your question may change the methodology that you use.

Let us assume that you have worked out the physics of your particles, that you have a probability distribution and a model.  You have collected your data.  What you have not clearly described is "so what?"

You stated

> Specifically, I calculate the probability of a random particle forming an aggregate of a particular size

None of us know how to actually do that.  It is an unsolvable problem.  What we can tell you are multiple competing ways to model this problem, but some are better than others depending on the usage and underlying facts.  Unless it is a toy problem, there will be things that domain experts know that we do not which are built into the problem.  If we knew them, it may change the rules to model the system.  For example, if there were boundary conditions, it may change the probability estimates.

There is nothing wrong with binning the data as you have and using that as an estimate of your probability.  The rest of the histogram doesn't matter because you can approximately answer the question of $\Pr(a<X<b)$ for the one bin of interest.  That assumes that your sample is representative and large enough.

Your intuition is correct, though, that knowing the distribution could allow better statements about probabilities.  The reason is that if you know the shape of the population, or the sampling distribution of an average when using averages, and your empirical shape does not match, then you can incorporate the uncertainty of your estimate into your probability estimate.

If your data is lopsided and you believe it should be symmetric, then you can still make reasonably accurate statements despite the fact the sample does not conform to the population.  Conversely, if your data is symmetric and you believe it should be lopsided, you can still make accurate statements despite its symmetry.

Finally, the explicit question at the top of the page is:

> Why are raw data analyzed rather than the probability distribution the data are sampled from?

Some methods use the likelihood function, which is closely related to the probability distribution involved, to analyze data.  It is a very powerful tool to use, provided that you get the distribution correct.  Then the raw data is analyzed with respect to the distribution involved explicitly.

On the other hand, there are methods that do not use the likelihood function.  Their advantage is that they work on many or even all possible probability distributions.  Their solutions are robust but do not have as much precision.

Unlike other areas of mathematics, the field of statistics lacks uniqueness proofs.    There is rarely just one way to do things.

Binning data, as long as the sample is large enough and representative, works fine.  Implicitly, the physics are present in the histogram.  If you can be explicit about the math involved, there may be a way to improve your estimate.

The difference is the difference between using calculus in physics and using no math at all.  You could perform a very large number of experiments on a specific phenomenon in a narrow way to determine outcomes.  If you could convert the system to a set of equations, however, you can generalize them and determine if there is an effect in the system that you had not accounted for.  You also would need less data to determine the same thing that more data provided in the experiment-only case.

The former works well but is very expensive.  The latter costs less and allows you a warning that all is not as you believe it should be.  Some branches of statistics analyze data with respect to distribution and some do not.  Your goal should determine what method you use.